# How could I block a website from opening on my computer

Tags: internet

How could I block a website from opening on my computer regardless of the browser I use . I tried modifying the host file with no success so far . Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One of 2 options I can think of right this second.  Edit the host file or block it in windows firewall.

host: 
Let's say you want to block google.com

Open notepad as administrator, find notepad in the Start menu, right click, open as admin or search for notepad in the search bar in the start menu and right click open as admin.

Once notepad is opened goto:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

Open the hosts file

Add under all the text a line by itself without a # in front of it (# means that line is a comment and will do nothing).

to block google for instance:

```
0.0.0.0 google.com
```

Save

Now when you go to google.com in any browser, it tries to grab the page from the 0.0.0.0 ip which goes no-where.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem has been solved, but for completeness I'll add this: [Firefox Addon - Kitten Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/kitten-block/)

Because you probably want to put something on one of these browsers in addition to the system 32 solution say, because the "unable to connect" page is a rubbish place to keep going.

Comment: What a fantastic add-on!

Comment: *regardless of the browser* -- I'd say a Firefox addon is pretty browser-specific...

Comment: I'm saying you make the actual changes in system32 but you cover it up on the browser level for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: There are probably more boring scripts for this you can run on greasemonkey (e.g.) for non-mozilla-fans.

Comment: Unfortunately , the site somehow worked again after it was blocked. The method I tried is obviously not  working .

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's redirected website if so blocking via host does not work until you enter the redirected web address in host file.

Comment: Thanks, Kaveh . I have just solved the problem . I used a program called hostsman and the website is blocked :)

Comment: wow great!, that's a very handy tool. thanks for recommended it to me.